# How to add Icon to react-leaflet Map component

Tags: react-leaflet

I am using non-geographic leaflet map in ReactJs, by using react-leaflet lib.

I am receiving an error that there is no default icon on default path and I need to include manually this icon.

```
   <Marker position={text['coordinates']} icon={"???"}>
        <Tooltip direction={"center"} permanent className={'shape-tooltip'}>
             <span>{text['text']}</span>
        </Tooltip>
    </Marker>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed to add native leaflet icon.

```
let icon = L.icon({
     iconRetinaUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png'),
     iconUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png'),
     shadowUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png')
})


   <Marker position={text['coordinates']} icon={icon}>
        <Tooltip direction={"center"} permanent className={'shape-tooltip'}>
             <span>{text['text']}</span>
        </Tooltip>
    </Marker>
```

As I guess there is no react-leaflet icon component so it must be created from native leaflet lib.